# Can an asp.net app integrate with a Google App

Tags: asp.net, google-apps, google-gadget, webservices-client

Looking to drive the content displayed on my Google Apps domain by using my IIS7-based webservice.  Would it be more productive to ask *'how can i drive a Google Gadget with asp.net'?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact you are supplying your content through a web service means it does not matter if you are using Asp.Net, Python, Java or anything.  The web service is an app that runs on much lower and standard protocols, meaning it can be consumed by any technology that can work with these protocols.

So the answer is yes, you can.